# Download file to certain client drive path

Tags: javascript, flash, air

I have web application
and i have situation i need to download file (on button click) to certain path  in the client 
without the browser download dialog box
using chrome (in IE im using activex).

what is the simplest way to do it?

The file is small text file (xml).

I know i have to use external application (flash...) 
but i didn't find any info about how to do it or if there is other way

(i prefer to avoid using flash because my knowledge in flash is very limited)

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the only things that you can download from a browser without the user's interaction (and without using plugins, add-ons, activex, applets, ...) are cookies and HTML5 local storage, otherwise that will be a very serious security problem if a website can download any content to the user's machine without his permission and to a certain path .

Even Flash, can not do that, you should always get the user's permission to download something except SharedObjects which are the Flash Player cookies (can be disabled as the browser's cookies).

For AIR, you can not use an AIR app in the browser.

Hope that can help.

Comment: well i can't use html5(my client using old environments systems). so there is a way (even flash or any plugin or extension)  that will lets me do that after i install them one time (after user permission of course - like activex) and i can use them to do that for me in chrome?

Comment: @user986474 I don't know for you need that XML content, may be we can find another approach, but for Chrome, you can write you own [Chrome Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) ...

Comment: i try to create chrome extension but still it's ask me where to save the file.

Comment: i try using chrome.filesystme - https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem  and as far as i can see chrome extension will not let me save the file if the user not accept it. there is other way?

Comment: @user986474 It's been a while since I did something with Chrome extensions, I really don't remember details, but I think there is some permissions ("storage" permission) to set when user install the extension/app (like for mobile apps) ...

Comment: @user986474 Take a look on some [samples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples) ...

Comment: it's look like there is now way to do that only by usgin chrome extension. "storage" permission not helping it this case